# Turning off preview fonts in TinyMCE custom style menu

Tags: tinymce

I have created some custom styles in my TinyMCE editor, that show up correct in the menu. The menu items are shown with the styling applied (as expected), but some of my styles are applied to img tags, and thus can't be represented the same way a paragraph or heading could. I tried using "previes_styles:false", but it also disables the styling of the default Format menu.

I would like to be able to disable this per style option, is that possible?

This page displays the default behavior, click the Formats menu to see the styled options. 
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/format-custom/

[image: Tiny MCE format menu]

I would like to disable styling on for instance "Red header", so it displays the text with default "menu style" - the same as a normal menu option.

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration option to do that:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#preview_styles

```
preview_styles: false
```